# Garmin etrex 10 and QGIS

Tags: qgis, gps, garmin

I want to know if anyone has been able to download data from a etrex 10/20/30 directly from Qgis. The usb protocol decsribe in a recent post does not do the trick. GpsBabel documentation
states that

> "This unit uses GPX format, not Garmin protocol. Therefore one should
>   communicate with it by reading and writing GPX files instead of using
>   this format. Members of this class of products do not support realtime
>   positioning protocol."

All I want is to be able to download my data within QGis

Thanks before hand

Gerardo

Comment: My eTrex 10 mounts as USB disk. Can't you load the GPX files from the USB drive? Let the OS worry about USB protocol, not QGIS.

Answer (score 2):

etrex 20 & 30 have microSD™ cards - you can read directly from the card from QGIS.

[image]

Note: Garmin Connect™ compatible (online community where you analyze, categorize and share data) so you can upload it then download the data to to view in QGIS.

Comment: That I understand, but for etrex 10 that does not have a microsd card?

Comment: You can upload the etrex10 to the Garmin Connect service and download it to your hard drive and open it from there with QGIS.

Answer (score 1):

I downloaded the Etrex data using DNRGarmin (it's free) to a text file; I then brought the file into QGIS using the "Add delimited text layer tool."  It's very easy, though you must make sure the data from the garmin isn't corrupted.  If it is, it will cause big problems.